# Maximum connections for GCM using Same Project Credentials

Tags: android, performance, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When I am sending multiple Push Notifications using Same username and password(project id and apikey), Remote host closed the connection. But it is working fine for single push notification.

Can anyone help me, how can i send multiple messages using same project id and apikey?

Comment: Do you want to send messages to one device?

Comment: NO. I want to send to the different Registration id, but project credentials are same.

Comment: It is already doing gcm.

Answer (score 0):

Max connections allowed by user is 100,
max outstanding messages per connection is 100.
Watch: [Google Cloud Messaging on youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owhf42SZadk)